# Can I use same action, effect and service to get values emitted from same endpoint with different payloads?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Here's my effect. I need to use the same service with different payload at two places to get data. Even when I unsubscribe after using it in my first component, it always gets overwritten when the new values are there for the second component.

Do I need to use a separate end point if the payload is different or there is another way to achieve this.

```js
@Effect()
    getCampaignProductUserCountEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<campaignAction.GetCampaignProductUserCountAction>(campaignAction.ActionTypes.GET_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT_USER_COUNT),
        withLatestFrom(this.store),
        switchMap(([action, state]) => {
            return this.campaignService.campaignProductUserCount(action.payload.data)
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap((response: any) => {
                        return of(new campaignAction.GetCampaignProductUserCountSuccessAction(response));
                    }),
                    catchError(error => 
                         of(new globalActions.PopupNotificationAction({
                            actionType: campaignAction.ActionTypes.GET_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT_USER_COUNT,
                            messageType: MessageType.Error,
                            message: error.error.message,
                            extraParameters: null,
                            error: error.error,
                            title: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.CAMPAIGN_TITLE
                        }))
                    ));
        })
    );
```

Here's the selector:

```js
const getCampaignProductUserCount = (state: CampaignState): boolean =>
    state && state.productUserCount && state.productUserCount.data
export const selectCampaignProductUserCount: MemoizedSelector<object, any> = createSelector(
    selectState,
    getCampaignProductUserCount
);
```

This is how I'm trying to use it in one of my components:

```
this.campaignStoreService.dispatchGetCampaignProductUserCount({ data: { productQuerys: { query: this.queries } }});
          this.campaignStoreService.selectGetCampaignProductUserCount().subscribe(data => {
            if(data) {
              this.getUserCountCallback(data);
              this.totalUserCount = data.userCount.userCount;
              this.totalReach = data.userCount.user_projection;
            }
          });
```

In one of the other components, I need to use the same thing but with different payload.

In this component, I am sending a set of queries to get the result and on other place I need to calculate the result of each individual query.

Service

```
campaignProductUserCount(data) {
    const url = this.apiConfig.getApiUrl() + API_PATH.CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT_USER_COUNT;
    return this.post(url, data);
  }
```

Originally when we only needed the count just once, we were fetching the number in the callback. Here's the effect(older):

```
@Effect()
    getCampaignProductUserCountEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<campaignAction.GetCampaignProductUserCountAction>(campaignAction.ActionTypes.GET_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT_USER_COUNT),
        withLatestFrom(this.store),
        switchMap(([action, state]) => {
            return this.campaignService.campaignProductUserCount(action.payload.data)
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap((response: any) => {
                        action.payload.callback && action.payload.callback({ success: true, response });
                        return of(new campaignAction.GetCampaignProductUserCountSuccessAction(response));
                    }),
                    catchError(error => {
                        action.payload.callback && action.payload.callback({ success: false });
                        return of(new globalActions.PopupNotificationAction({
                            actionType: campaignAction.ActionTypes.GET_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT_USER_COUNT,
                            messageType: MessageType.Error,
                            message: error.error.message,
                            extraParameters: null,
                            error: error.error,
                            title: MESSAGE_CONSTANTS.CAMPAIGN_TITLE
                        }))
                    }));
        })
    );
```

Is it possible for me to use the same callback method or I have to subscribe?

I am new to rxjs, so don't know if there is something wrong in choosing the correct operator or its something else.

Comment: If I follow, you could use a service that returns an instance of a new class (one that is not a service/component/etc.). The new class would do the heavy lifting. Basically the service would be a factory returning new instances of a class. I did that for a query builder service that I had that built and ran GraphQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although you unsubscibed but you are re-using the action and effect. You are still calling the same success action i.e., GetCampaignProductUserCountSuccessAction. Hence it will call the same reducer and your previous data will be overridden.

First of all you should never reuse action for multiple jobs. Each action should have a specific role to do [single responsibilty]. The same goes for effects.

You can have common service to fetch the resources.

Also, you are usng combineLatestFrom in your effect but I do not see any usage in your effect.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have added the older code for the effect where we were using it one time only. Since this time this calculation had to be done dynamically, so subscription was a better idea.